# how to properly organize the work of a small piece of code in a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unique-ptr

I want to run a small piece of C++ code in a separate thread every 20 seconds.

```
// std::unique_ptr<databaseServer> database
// std::vector<std::unique_ptr<databaseServer>> databases_list_

    while (is_work_) {

        for (auto& database : databases_list_) {
            if (db_conn_status == connection_status::connected) {

                { // I want to run this piece of code in a separate thread
                std::string stats_query = "SYSTEM_VOC";
                auto db_stats = database->send_command(stats_query, command_type::get_stats);
                const auto getdata_result = cmd_parser::getstat_command(db_stats);
                if (getdata_result.success == true)
                   mtrcs.inc_stat_data(getdata_result.queue_voc);
                }

                auto db_respond = database->send_command(receive_channel_cmd, command_type::get_data);

            }
            else if (db_conn_status == connection_status::disconnected) {
                   database->reconnect();
            }
        }   
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(processing_period_));
    }
```

The problem is that in this code there is a "database" parameter which is of type std::unique_ptr.
So the 'database' parameter changes in the 'while' loop.
I don't know how to properly organize the work of this small piece of code in a separate thread.

Comment: It occurs to me the work is already split in small pieces.. Unless there are side-effects to each iteration of the loop, they could all run in separate threads?!

Comment: Have a look at std::async to start your function, not sure if your database library is threadsafe though (so you might need some mutexes).

Comment: @PepijnKramer, You're right. I get an error if I just run this little piece of code on a thread:
`std::thread([this, &database]() { ...piece of code... }`
How to fix it?

Comment: The details of what is actually going on (and what your error is) are not clear enough to me to give you an answer.  It could also be that by the time a thread executes the life cycle of `database` has ended (access violation). It could be that your multiple send_command calls to the start to overlap and the database (API) can't handle that (and the threading will not work at all).  Nobody said multithreading was easy and in that respect ALL the details matter.